# How do I get a button id or value from x-on:click in Alpine JS?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Looking to extract a value or id in Alpine JS onclick, I thought `this.id` or `this.value` would work but no luck.

Returns

> Alpine Expression Error: Can't find variable: id

```
<button id="myBtn" value="100" x-on:click="alert(this.id);">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

`<button @click="alert($event.target.getAttribute('message'))" message="Hello World">Say Hi</button>`

$event.target will give you access to the clicked element.

Ref: https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#the-event-object

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Event with $event. Then you can handle it like in vanilaJs.

```js
function hello(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute('id'))
}
```

```html
 <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>    
<button id="myBtn" value="100" @click="hello($event);">Save</button>
```

Comment: This worked too but I can keep it all inline as above.  Thank you for your time.